# TypeError when trying to run npm init in blank folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to get into Discord bot making, and I have node installed, version 17.3.0.

When I try to run `npm init` in a blank folder on my desktop, it throws me this error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
```

It will throw me this error when I try to run any npm command. I have never seen any error like this before in this situation, and I haven't found any other person via google that's encountered this situation.

Any help is appreciated. I could be (probably am) overlooking something extremely simple and overthinking the f out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

The issue ended up being there was an old install of Node on my computer that did not properly uninstall when I tried to uninstall it. This caused all my issues. Thank you to everyone who tried to help, problem solved.

If anyone comes across this issue, the old version will be located in your nvm folder within your AppData directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird one. I would suggest using Node 16.13.1 LTS instead. LTS means Long Term Support. This means that it is probably more stable than that Node calls the "current" version. Also, since you are using Windows, try the installers available on Node.js' homepage instead of nvm. I've had issues with nvm in the past, though I've never tried it on Windows.

Comment: Downgraded to 16.13.1, still the same issue. Would a better route just to uninstall Visual Studio Code, and reinstall that? maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @dmesser Seems to be a problem with the node version manager - looking at socks-proxy-agent maybe something with the namespace and windows - but that's just an assumption.. I'd also recommend to use the latest LTS version instead, especially on windows ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix I'm not quite sure what you're telling me to do (besides change Node version again)... what exactly is socks-proxy-agent? and how would I change that?

Comment: Based on that directory path you're somehow using v14 rather than v17 as you intended. Unsure why the error is occurring but agree that installing using the official installer is probably the best bet if you aren't jumping between lots of projects with different version requirements (which is when nvm is most useful)

Comment: @Michael I've only ever installed Node via the official installer directly from the Node.js website... so now I'm extra confused lol.

Comment: @dmesser _"I'm not quite sure what you're telling me to do"_ If you would read and comprehend the  trace you posted and visit to the github-repo of nvm's socks-proxy-agent of that version you maybe would..

Comment: @iLuvLogix You could have just said that in the first place, I didn't know there was a github repo for socks-proxy-agent. No need to be snippy when I was looking for clarity when I clearly didn't understand.

Comment: @dmesser _" I'm not quite sure what you're telling me to do (besides change Node version again)"_ sounds rather snarky and snippy to me if someone tries to help you, but anyways - enjoy and learn!

Comment: The paths in the error stack trace you posted suggest that nvm is being used. The letters "nvm" appear literally there.  Can you check that somehow nvm didn't get installed? Maybe uninstall node then delete C:\Users\bluep\AppData\Roaming\nvm\ and try installing again.